# IntelliJ Shift Shift Shortcut in Visual Studio (Global Search)

Tags: visual-studio, intellij-idea, shortcut, shift

After doing some Java I fell in love with some of IntelliJ's features. Especially the keyboard shortcut <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> +<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>  which lets you jump to any other file.

This is a huge time savesaver. Now that I'm back in VS I really miss that feature when I'm editing code. Is there any way to reproduce this in Visual Studio? Perhaps a plugin of some sort?

Comment: Try [ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/)

Comment: Im a long time ReSharper user, Is there a hidden feature I dont know about?

Comment: @AlexVPerl Did you come up with any solution to your question?

Comment: @Devl11 Yes, this is finally part of latest ReSharper, check out my answer below on how to access it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few years later and ReSharper now has this feature in the latest version.

It's called **Search Everywhere/Go to Type** and is triggered with shortcut **CTRL + N**

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Navigation_and_Search__Go_to_Type.html

Extremely useful feature, saves you lots of time and allows you to jump to other files while editing code. Once you try it, using Solution Explorer feels like a waste of time. I got used to it while using IntelliJ IDEA & Android Studio, glad it's now available in Visual Studio via ReSharper.

[image]

Answer (score 34):

It's became possible after the recently VS Code release(1.54.0 or above), you can update `keybindings.json` with following code:

```
[
{
    "key": "shift shift",
    "command": "workbench.action.quickOpen"
},
{
    "key": "alt alt",
    "command": "workbench.action.quickOpen"
},
{
    "key": "ctrl ctrl",
    "command": "workbench.action.showCommands"
}
]
```

Source: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/5280#issuecomment-767869212

Or install VS Code extension: `shift shift`

Comment: The `shift shift` extension only searches for files but not for strings inside files as pycharm does.

Comment: This is a useful answer for VS Code but the question is referring to *Visual Studio*

Comment: Although this answer Is not on the topic (VS), but rather VSCode - I still upvoted it, especially since it pops up as a first result for `visual studio code double shiftt`. Thank you, kind sir

Comment: MS did a bad job of naming VS Code. MS often sucks at naming things (.NET).

Answer (score 10):

No need for ReSharper since Visual Studio 17 has already implemented a similar feature:

**CTRL + T**

[image]

Comment: For Mac users: "CMD + T"

Comment: "Go to All" sadly doesn't search all content--only files, types, members, and symbols. Currently in Visual Studio one has to use Ctrl+Shift+F if searching text/code or Ctrl+T / Ctrl+comma to search "things". I'd love it if there was an extension that did only the search/find functionality of Resharper.

Answer (score 8):

Not exactly the same (doesn't show the last used/opened tabs), but works to jump to a file (might be VS 2013+ only):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> then type your search terms, you can use space for different parts of the file name:
`con na ex` => **Con**trol**Na**me**Ex**plorer

I find it easier to use when disabling the Preview Tab (click on the down arrow at the right of the search box to change settings).

[More details here](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2014/05/19/code-navigation-resharper-80-vs-visual-studio-2013/).

**EDIT**
This shortcut is set when installing ReSharper, but you can manually set it to the command `Edit.NavigateTo` (Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard).

**EDIT for VS2017**
The command is now named `Edit.GoToAll`. Thanks to Matt for pointing it out.

Comment: `Edit.NavigateTo` has changed to `Edit.GoToAll` (see blog post [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/11/16/introducing-go-to-the-successor-to-navigate-to/)). It doesn't seem to allow you to create a shortcut with Shift, Shift, however.

Comment: @Loren I think this is only in VS Code, not in Visual Studio.

Comment: "Go to All" sadly doesn't search all content--only files, types, members, and symbols. Currently in Visual Studio one has to use Ctrl+Shift+F if searching text/code or Ctrl+T / Ctrl+comma to search "things". I'd love it if there was an extension that did only the search/find functionality of Resharper.

Answer (score -7):

Not really sure what <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> does, does that mean holding down both <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> keys and pressing <kbd>J</kbd>?

I find I seldom need to goto a file. I put my cursor on a variable or a function, hit <kbd>F12</kbd> and it goes to wherever it is defined, without me needing to remember it. If I press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd> it gives a list of every where it is referenced, again without needing to remember.  If I want to go back to where I was at I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> (which works in any context).  I am quite comfortable with this navigation, and so like you, every time I try something new the first thing I do is try to find out how they implement what I am already used to.

Comment: Its hitting shift 2x in a row. Great shortcut and time saver.